# How do I programmatically delete a reference field value?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a multi-valued taxonomy reference field named `field_classrooms` in a node type. I use below code to delete the value in the field.

```
$node = Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load('1512');
unset($node->field_classrooms[0]);
$node->save();
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe something like this could help you out

```
// Get the list of the associated classrooms ...
$classrooms = $node->get('field_classrooms')->getValue();
// ... if there are any associated classrooms ...
if(!empty($classrooms)) {
  foreach($classrooms as $classroom) {
    // ... get the key of the classroom
    $key = array_search(current($classroom), array_column($classrooms, key($classroom)));
    // ... remove the relationship ...
    $node->get('field_classrooms')->removeItem($key);
  }
  // ... and save the node.
  $node->save();
}
```

If you want to remove a single classroom from the list and you already know the tid

```
private function removeClassroomFromNode($node, $tid) {
  if(null != $node) {
    // ... get the list of associated classrooms
    $classrooms = $node->get('field_classrooms')->getValue();
    // ... get the key of the classroom
    $key = array_search($tid, array_column($classrooms, 'target_id'));
    // ... remove the classroom
    $node->get('field_classrooms')->removeItem($key);
    // ... save the node.
    $node->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried `removeItem` instead of `unset` but still it doesn't seem to remove the value. It is a multi value field btw.

Comment: The `removeItem()` method uses `unset()`
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Plugin%21DataType%21ItemList.php/function/ItemList%3A%3AremoveItem/8.4.x

Comment: So unnecessarily complex ... Drupal is something else...

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code for removing items in the reference field in Drupal 8 :

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase $entity */
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);

$tids = $entity->get('field_classrooms')->getValue();

$updatedTerms = [];
foreach($tids as $term) {
  if ($term['target_id'] != 35)
    $updatedTerms[] = ['target_id' => $term['target_id']];      
}

$entity->field_notifications = $updatedTerms;

$entity->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set to empty

```
$node->set('field_classrooms', []);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the first item of a list just calling

```
$node->get('field_classrooms')->removeItem(0);
```

Comment: Ya but you're shooting in the dark - how do you know which index to delete?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a particular referenced entity by id with this code:

```
    $entity->get('my_field')->setValue(array_filter($entity->get('my_field')->getValue(), function ($value) use ($id) {
      return ($value['target_id'] != $id);
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of bulk or selective delete is elegant `filter()` method.

Example:

```
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataInterface;

$nodeStorage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node');
/**
 * @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node
 */
$node = $nodeStorage->load($nid);
$classrooms = $node->get('field_classrooms');
$classrooms->filter(function (TypedDataInterface $item) {
  // You can do some operations on field item like: $item->getValue();
  // Returning TRUE in an iteration will remove the item.
  return TRUE;
});
$node->save();
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the winner for me because the `filter()` function lets you remove more than one entity reference in one go.

If you try to do this with a loop you always end up with array indexing errors.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile you can take help from this code -

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load('1512');
// Removes '0' index element.
$node->set('field_classrooms', array_slice($node->get('field_classrooms')->getValue(), 1));
$node->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

the item is removed based on the index number of the list, so you need to figure out the index you want to remove,

1.- get all the referenced items

`$array_of_referenced_items = $node->get('field_SOMETHING_ref')->getValue();`

2.- search on the array for the index of the item you are trying to remove.

`$index_to_remove = array_search(['target_id' => ID_TO_SEARCH], $array_of_referenced_items);`

3.- Remove the reference by the index.

`$node->get('field_SOMETHING_ref')->removeItem($index_to_remove);`